# Click event is not working javaScript in odoo

Tags: odoo-16

I'm encountering an issue with a useListener hook in my Odoo project. It doesn't seem to work, and I'm seeking assistance to identify and resolve the problem. Here are the details of my situation:

**Context:**
Odoo version: 16

**Problem Description:**

I have a custom module in Odoo where I'm trying to use a useListener hook event to trigger a specific action, but it doesn't work. I have a console statement in my code which is getting printed. Here's a simplified example of my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
odoo.define("my_custom_module.sale", function(require) {
    'use strict'

    const { useListener } = require("@web/core/utils/hooks");
    console.log('test====');

    class FeatureScreen   {
        setup() {
          useListener('increase', this.increaseQuantity);
        }
        increaseQuantity(event) {
            var self = this;
            console.log("click worked")
        }
    }

    FeatureScreen.template = 'featureScreen';

    return FeatureScreen;

})
```

**View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <!-- This contains the tour assets. They are included during testing. -->
   <template id="feature_index" name="Index">
      &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>No title</title>
         </head>
         <body class="o_web_client">
            <div class="container-fluid pt-4">
               <div class="product-list row">
                  <div class="col-3">
                     <t t-name="featureScreen" owl="1">
                        <div class="value-button"
                           t-on-click="() => this.trigger('increase')"
                           value="Increase Value">cdd
                        </div>
                     </t>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Add more products here -->
               </div>
            </div>
            <t t-call="my_custom_module.assets_common"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </template>
</odoo>
```